# Is it possible to get an Estimated Time of Completion / monitor progress from a Windows Subprocess in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess

While I am specifically curious about Robocopy, I am wondering if it is possible to get an estimated time of completion for a subprocess in Python (which would be opened with the `Popen` method.

Robobcopy itself has flags to set for the ETA of a file copy however these are per file and not for the whole task.

I have easily been able to get the output from standard out but this hasn't helped me predict when a task will be done.

Comment: It's not possible (it's called the Halting Problem).

Comment: If you are able to extract the metrics for the first files (like MB/s, files/s, latency) then you can do a statistical analysis and based on that an educated guess on the time it might take. Basically hard to do and not reliable.